# Magento Nginx: Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

Tags: magento, nginx, url-rewriting

I install my Magento CE 1.8.1 on Nginx server.

My nginx conf file is like this: [Configuring nginx for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento#individual_sites)

I created a subfolder in Magento root folder, then put in it some php files.
I tried to execute those files by visiting urls (http://example.com/magento/subfolder/myfile.php) but it displays Magento 404 page. That means it was forced to rewrite by conf.

I looked into Magento default .htaccess file and found these lines:

```
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

How to convert this into nginx conf and make existing files executable?

Comment: # nginx configuration

location / {
}

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: in Nginx conf file already had `location /` part.

Comment: it will give only location / {} for your .htaccess ReqriteCond. You can share you full .htaccess

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: my .htacess is the default (generated by Magento), anyway, the .htacess isn't used by nginx server.

I cannot paste full .htacess content because of the length.

Comment: Try this to convert an Apache's .htaccess to nginx configuration: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I already tried this before, but it didn't work.